# Are brown and maroon different colors?

Tags: word-meaning, etymology

I make this question because in my language Spanish, brown is translated as marrón, and both marrón and maroon looks related in origins (same with the french marron I suppose). If they are all related in origins my guess it's they all should refer to the same color, but it would seem brown and maroon are used as different colors in English? If so the english maroon and the spanish marrón ended refering to different colors?

Comment: "If they are all related in origins my guess it's they all should refer to the same color", why do you think so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maroon is a kind of dark red; brown is, well, brown.

[image]
Maroon

[image]
Brown

Comment: note that despite the etymology, "maroon" and "chestnut" are rather different colours.